# read jpg into a 2d array of pixels in CPP

Tags: c++, image, jpeg

Disclaimer: big noob
I've read enough to understand that decompressing jpg is a huge mess, so I've tried boost (getting a huge, obtuse error) and I'm just trying to understand the best method/utility to pull in a jpg file, read it into a 2d array of pixels (pixels being a stand-in for a 3 element array for RGB), and then do some operations on those pixels. The total block I'm having is how to actually get the jpg into a workable format. Should I just convert it to BMP using a library and then go from there?

Comment: Use the library, Luke. That's what they are there for. But seriously, jpg is a lot of math making the image as small as possible without winding up with a grey blob. Can you write your own jpg decoder? Sure you can. Had to do it myself back in school for a signal processing class. Was it fun? Not really.

Comment: yeah that answers it, wish i would have seen that earlier.